# Surround C# code with curly braces functionality is gone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper

When I have selected piece of C# or C++ code in Visual Studio, I've got used that pressing the button '{' would surround the *code* with braces like so {*code*}.

After installation of VS 2017 this functionlality is gone for C#, but it is still the same for C++. So now, when I press '{' on selected C# code, it just gets replaced by '{' symbol.

As I've always been using VS + Resharper bundle, I have no idea which one has changed its behaviour.
I shall really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

I know that I can get the same effect by using "surround with block" functionality, but my question is how to get back this handy one-button feature as it was before

Comment: Select your code -> Hit alt + enter and select surround with block

Comment: ctrl + k, ctrl + s works for me with resharper

Comment: None of ReSharper release builds has this feature for C# or C++. However, we added such feature for C# to ReSharper 2017.3 EAP 6 a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen the feature you describe, but there is an alternative which is working in VS2017 and Resharper2017

In the default configuration you just need to select your code and hit **alt + enter**. A popup will appear. In this popup select "Surround with block"

[image: Shows the popup menu]